# How can the parameter for string.format cut the string

Tags: c#, .net, string.format

I need to make a possibility to open a webpage either with an additional parameter or without one. If it has a parameter, I'll add it with the string.format function. Sometimes I need to format this parameter before opening the url, however, I don't want to make the code too specific.

The Parameter is always a string and I would need to cut the end of this string. Is it possible to do something in the string to be formatted to cut the unneeded text? If so how would the {0} have to look that it works?

```
        string url = "http://foo.bar/xt:{0}";
        string parameter = "abcdefghi";
        if (Regex.Matches(Regex.Replace(url,
            @"(\{{2}|\}{2})", ""), // removes escaped curly brackets
            @"\{(\d+)(?:\:?[^}]*)\}")
            .OfType<Match>().Any())
        {
            Process.Start(string.Format(url, parameter));
        }
        else
        {
            Process.Start(url);
        }
```

Instead of abcdefghi I would like to have as parameter just abcdefg for instance. But this should be configurable via url. Something like {0:7) or so...

Comment: It is really unclear what you're trying to accomplish. Do you want to _truncate_ a string? Can you show example input and output?

Answer (score 0):

You have to write this kind of logic yourself. What you can do, however, is wrap this in an extension method so you don't have to duplicate it everywhere:

```
public static class StringExt
{
    public static string Truncate(this string value, int maxLength)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) return value;
        return value.Length <= maxLength ? value : value.Substring(0, maxLength); 
    }
}
```

Now we can write:

```
var someString = "...";
someString = someString.Truncate(2);
```

Comment: May be a if condition should be added before someString.Truncate(2); as if(someString != null) .!